# How do you enable the expose feature on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, desktop

the other day I was moving my laptop with wireless mouse. I accidentally dropped my mouse and I don't know which buttons were clicked.  However, the expose feature (just like on a Mac) came up and I was really impressed!  I like Mac and own one, but am still a Windows guy at heart.  Anyone know?  I am not talking about installing external software, I know the feature is built into Windows 8 because I saw it firsthand.  Searches for expose, tips and tricks online turned up nothing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out.  I love Microsoft...  This might work with any external mouse supporting three buttons.  I am using a wireless Microsoft USB mouse with three buttons, with the middle supporting scroll functionality (a wheel).  If I hold the left or right mouse button down and then click the scroll wheel, the expose comes up.  I can also let go of both buttons so that if I use my scrolling, I can select which application I want to focus on (or just click the app you want too).  The only thing I did not figure out is that when this first happened, the apps surrounded my desktop in the expose.  This time, they just appear as an organized grid.  Solution by webappguy-dot-com.

Comment: If this is the answer, don't forget to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

windows 8 has no native "expose" like mac has.
still, there is software around the web that can do it.

to trigger app scrolling do **alt+tab**

Comment: Nope, disagree.  I asked the question above because I saw with my own eyes after dropping my mouse.

Comment: The feature is not part of Windows. It is something added by your mouse driver.

Comment: Thanks Raymond.  But, my mouse is two years older than my copy of Windows 8.

Comment: issue solved then? **mouse buttons press + scroll** organizes default windows *alt+tab* as a grid?